# How to delete everything before a variable number with Perl/Regex

Tags: regex, perl

I'm cleaning a file with Perl and I have one line that is a bit tough to work with.

It looks something like:

```
^L#$%@@$^%^3456 [rest of string]
```

but I need to get rid of everything before the `3456`

the issue is that the `3456` change every single time, so I need to use a sed command that is non specific. I should also add that the stuff before the `3456` will never be numbers

now `s/^.*$someString/$someString/` works when i'm working with strings, but the same line doesn't work when it's not a string.

anyway, please help!

Comment: Regex needs patterns to match, and you haven't really supplied enough to work with. Would the part you need removed always consist of non-word characters?

Comment: it can be anything besides a number.

Comment: Would the amount of garbage you need removed be the same every time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will remove all non-numbers from beginning of the line,

```
s/^ \D+ //x;
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want a regular expression with a lookahead, plus non-greedy matching.

A lookahead is a pattern that would match at the current position, but doesn't consume characters:

```
my $str = "abc";
$str =~ s/a(?=b)//; # $str eq "bc"
```

Non-greedy matching modifies the `*` or `+` operator by appending a `?`. It will now match as few characters as possible.

```
$str = "abab";
$str =~ s/.*(?=b)//; # $str eq "b"
$str = "abab";
$str =~ s/.*?(?=b)//; # $str eq "bab"
```

To interpolate a string that should never be treated as a pattern, protect it with `\Q...\E`:

```
$re = "^foo.?"
$str = "abc^foo.?baz";
$str =~ s/^.*?(?=\Q$re\E)//; # $str eq "baz"
```

Answer (score 0):

> I need to get rid of everything before the 3456

`(?:(?!STRING).)*` is to `STRING` as `[^CHAR]*` is to `CHAR`, so

```
s/^(?:(?!3456).)*//s;
```

It can also be done using the non-greedy modifier (`.*?`), but I dislike using it.

```
s/^.*?3456/3456/s;
s/^.*?(3456)/$1/s;  # Without duplication.
s/^.*?(?=3456)//s;  # Without the performance penalty of captures.
```